# Display Joomla article contents and title using PHP

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, articles, com-content, custom-module

I have a component and module built by an external company, they have hardcoded content into the component - I want to change it so the content is called from the Joomla Article Manager.

The component uses individual codes (called by '+nugget.code+') that I want to match up to a Joomla article, with the same name.

For example, if the code (within the component) is AB1, I want it to load an article that has the title of 'AB1'.

What would I need to write to include Joomla content in an external component?

I have tried:

```
$article_id = +nugget.code +  ": " +nugget.name + ;
$article =& JTable::getInstance("content");
$article->load($article_id);

var $heading = $('<h5>'. $article->get("title").'</h5>');
$text.append($heading);
```

But this isn't working.

The external component calls "+nugget.code +" - (which in this example, let's say the value is "REI1")

The external component also calls "+nugget.name +" - (which in this example, let's say the value is "Test Article")

So '+nugget.code +": "+nugget.name+' would be 'REI1: Test Article'

What I want, is if there is a Joomla article called 'REI1: Test Article', that then needs to be shown.

Comment: `$article_id` should represent the content id. In Joomla! it is in number format.

Comment: Can you please describe more about `nugget.code` and `nugget.name`? What type of values they hold in system?

Comment: I've just updated the question with details, thanks SD

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any direct code that will help you to get article based on **article title**. But I can see one way to get this done is as follow:

Check com_content model for function `getListQuery` at this path: `/administrator/components/com_content/models/articles.php` This function is used to query articles from database, based on filters and search query passed at back-end.

You can use inherit this class to use this function or directly take logic form it. To get search result, you need to store article title as follow:

`$this->setState('filter.search', "+nugget.code +": "+nugget.name+");`

OR

`$this->setState('filter.search', $articleTitle);`

Where `$articleTitle` holds title value of your article.

> The better way is to use the logic from this function and remove unwanted filter queries & `IF` conditions from core logic.